# How do I find source of Failed Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am using `COM` library whose responsibility is to connect to the server and do some operation. So I have subscribed to below events.

```
 comHA = new COMlib.ComHA();
 comHA.onConnectSucceeded += Handle_OnConnectSucceeded;
 comHA.onConnectFailed += Handle_OnConnectFailed;
```

I am looping through all devices and trying to connect them as follow

```
foreach (ICtrlConnection host in initialHosts)
{
     comHA.connectByNameEx("ssl", "serverexample.com", credentials, null);
}
```

Here is the `Handle_OnConnectFailed` code which fires for few of devices.

```
 void Handle_OnConnectFailed(int hr)
    {
        string msg = "Unknown Error";
        try
        {
            msg = prxCmn.MessageForID((uint)hr);
            msg = msg.Replace("\r\n", " ");
            _logger.Error(msg);

        }
        catch (Exception){}            
    }
```

**Problem**:  I am getting just error number `hr`, but i cannot make out which device is not able to connect! so how do I send device identifier to `Handle_OnConnectFailed`

I tried to check `COM` code and see that here is the delegate, it's SDK and I do not have any control on it.

```
[ComVisible(false)]
[TypeLibType(16)]
public delegate void _ComGWEvents_onConnectFailedEventHandler(int hr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass identifier in your loop (names at least, so I think this is what you need). So I'd suggest the following:

1. define `private` variable, like `private string _controllerNme;`
2. inside your loop, you need to store contreller's name you try to connect:

   ```
   foreach (ICtrlConnection host in initialHosts)
   {
     _controllerNme = "serverexample.com";
     comHA.connectByNameEx("ssl", _controllerNme, credentials, null);
   }
   ```
3. Inside your event hadnler now you have access to `_controllerNme`, which can be used to show which controller failed, so just change the line:

   ```
   string msg = $"{_controllerNme}: Unknown Error";
   ```

Comment: it says "_controllerNme" does not exists

Comment: @kudlatiger Where do you get that error? Did you define it as private variable?

Comment: yes, private string _controllerNme; before foreach loop

Comment: @kudlatiger How? There shouldn't be anything, show your full code.

Comment: @kudlatiger Declare your variable in class, not inside a method